Aplicar dos animaciones a un elemento css al mismo tiempo
Tengo un problema aplicando dos animaciones en css, según los documentos se pueden aplicar dos animaciones al mismo tiempo a un elemento si están separadas por una ",". En este caso estoy implementando una animación a unos svg de unas ondas la cual hace que se muevan horizontalmente y verticalmente en bucle, pero por alguna razón solo se ejecuta la ultima animación definida. Al tener 4 ondas quiero que a cada una de mis ondas se vean afectadas por las mismas animaciones pero en tiempos diferentes. Si de algo sirve estoy utilizando ReactJs y Sass.
HTML
<svg
  className="waves"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  viewBox="0 24 150 28"
  preserveAspectRatio="none"
  shapeRendering="auto"
>
  <defs>
    <path
      id="gentle-wave"
      d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z"
    />
    <linearGradient id="bg4">
      <stop offset="0%" stopColor="rgba(252, 175, 60, 0.3)"></stop>
      <stop offset="7%" stopColor="rgba(252, 175, 60, 0.75)"></stop>
      <stop offset="25%" stopColor="rgba(252, 175, 60, 0.3)"></stop>
      <stop offset="50%" stopColor="rgba(252, 175, 60, 0.9)"></stop>
      <stop offset="75%" stopColor="rgba(252, 175, 60, 0.3)"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stopColor="rgba(252, 175, 60, 0.9)"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="bg3">
      <stop offset="0%" stopColor="rgba(249, 162, 44, 0.6)"></stop>
      <stop offset="50%" stopColor="rgba(249, 162, 44, 0.9)"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stopColor="rgba(249, 162, 44, 0.3)"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="bg2">
      <stop offset="0%" stopColor="rgba(245, 148, 26, 0.6)"></stop>
      <stop offset="50%" stopColor="rgba(245, 148, 26, 0.9)"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stopColor="rgba(245, 148, 26, 0.3)"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="bg1">
      <stop offset="0%" stopColor="rgba(242, 133, 0, 0.6)"></stop>
      <stop offset="50%" stopColor="rgba(242, 133, 0, 0.9)"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stopColor="rgba(242, 133, 0, 0.3)"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g className="wavy">
    <use xlinkHref="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="0" fill="url(#bg4)" />
    <use xlinkHref="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="6" fill="url(#bg3)" />
    <use xlinkHref="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="4" fill="url(#bg2)" />
    <use xlinkHref="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="2" fill="url(#bg1)" />
  </g>
</svg>


SCSS
.waves {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  max-height: 20dvh;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* CSS Animation Code */

.wavy > use {
  z-index: 5;
}

.wavy > use:nth-child(1) {
  animation:
    move-forever 7s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.5, 0.45, 0.5) 0s infinite,
    swell 2s ease -1.25s infinite;
}

.wavy > use:nth-child(2) {
  animation:
    move-forever 6s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.5, 0.45, 0.5) 0s infinite,
    swell 1.5s ease -1.25s infinite;
}

.wavy > use:nth-child(3) {
  animation:
    move-forever 6.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.5, 0.45, 0.5) 0s infinite,
    swell 2.5s ease -1s infinite;
}

.wavy > use:nth-child(4) {
  animation:
    move-forever 7s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.5, 0.45, 0.5) 0s infinite,
    swell 2s ease -1.25s infinite;
  rotate: 5deg;
}

@keyframes swell {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -2px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes move-forever {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(90px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-86px, 0, 0);
  }
}


Buenas, al definir animaciones separadas por comas, todas las animaciones se aplican al mismo conjunto de propiedades, pero no pueden tener tiempos de inicio o duraciones diferentes.
Para hacer lo que quieres, deberas de aplicar las animaciones en reglas CSS separadas, es decir, para nth-child(1) una animacion con sus caracteristicas, para nth-child(2) otra animacion con sus caracteristicas, etc, etc.
